# Fail to install PyX using Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pyx

I'm having problems installing python modules PyX, I received the following error when using pip:

```
$ pip install PyX
Collecting PyX
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyX (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external PyX to allow).
No matching distribution found for PyX
```

Then I tried conda install, but it cannot locate it. I also searched and found nothing. Then I tried pip allow external - doesn't work on either Cygwin or cmd:

```
$ pip install --allow-external pyx pyx
Collecting pyx
  Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pyx/pyx/0.14/PyX 0.14.tar.gz (2.5MB)
No files/directories in c:\cygwin\tmp\pip-build-vqqlqz\pyx\pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

I've never seen such error before. Anyone here has some suggestion please (installed under Anaconda preferred)? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes. As shown in the post already:)

Comment: There is (or was) a good blog post from Anaconda's creators on the issue. Fortunately it exists in webcache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:KnFhxI4_wMwJ:www.continuum.io/blog/conda%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=il . Maybe you can find an answer there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay here is one solution I just found. However, I still could not explain the previous errors.

Upon trying to manually install PyX (go to the local PyX directory):

```
$ python setup.py install
*** Sorry, this version of PyX runs on Python 3 only. ***
If you want to use PyX on Python 2, please use one of our old releases up to PyX 0.12.x, i.e. execute something like:

   pip install pyx==0.12.1
```

So then I tried:

```
$ pip install  --allow-external pyx pyx==0.12.1
```

Then it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As of this writing, using the `--allow-external` flag will yield the following deprecation message:

> DEPRECATION: --allow-external has been deprecated and will be removed
>   in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer
>   has any effect.

Executing `pip install pyx==0.12.1` should do.

On **OS X**, you may receive the following error:

> error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyx':
>   Permission denied

Using the `--user` flag should allow you to install the package:

`pip install pyx==0.12.1 --user`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of installation of PyX as follows :

1. launch the anaconda navigator,
2. launch IPython QTConsole,
3. type `pip install pyx`

Wait for the installation to complete.